# salt-ssh: ls -lS over all minions

Tags: parallel-processing, salt-stack

I want to run `ls -lS /var/log/somebase.log-*` over all SaltStack minions.

I want the result to look roughly like this:

```
Size     Host  File
2345678  foo   /var/log/somebase.log-20161112.gz
1234567  bar   /var/log/somebase.log-20161110.gz
1045678  foo   /var/log/somebase.log-20160912.gz
...
```

Comment: have you tried my solution ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein yes, it works. You get the bounty, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a script which gives similar output, currently tested on one minion only but i guess it will work correctly but it needs to be tested again to ensure.

```
$ { echo Host Size File ; for minion in local-pc; do sudo salt $minion cmd.run 'ls -lS /var/log/dnf.rpm.log-*' --out=json |  python -c "import sys, json; ret = [{'host': k, 'result' : v} for k,v in json.load(sys.stdin).items()]; print json.dumps(ret)" | jq -r '.[].result' | awk -v host=$minion {'print host" "$5" "$9'};done } | column -t
Host      Size  File
local-pc  5646  /var/log/dnf.rpm.log-20161113
local-pc  4165  /var/log/dnf.rpm.log-20161120
local-pc  4067  /var/log/dnf.rpm.log-20161030
local-pc  3682  /var/log/dnf.rpm.log-20161107
```

**Dependencies:**

- [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)
- python

**Limitations:**

Minions must be connected. You may need to create a list of connected minions using `manage.up` then loop through this list by modifying the above code.

I will try to do more tests in order to provide a full solution.

Update:

Just noticed `salt-ssh` in the title, the code above works for minions, I didn't work with `salt-ssh` before. but if you got an issue let me know